# How to only hook on Single.php after content?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions

I am currently hooking on `the_content()` but that goes through the Wordpress loop too. How can I only hook on the Single.php page?

Also, is there a way to only look on the first X posts in the Wordpress loop?

By the way, I am creating a plugin

Comment: You want to add extra stuff to the end of the_content, but you only want it to happen when on single.php?

Comment: Yes. Also, I wanted to add something at the bottom of the content for the X most recent posts.

Comment: You should probably expand your question a little more, because right now it doesn't make much sense.  If you want to modify `single.php`, open up `single.php` and modify it.  By its nature, `single.php` will only have a single post in the loop.  To get other posts, you'll need a secondary loop after your main loop.

Comment: I am creating a plugin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will handle appending the content to single posts:

```
function yourprefix_add_to_content( $content ) {    
    if( is_single() ) {
        $content .= 'Your new content here';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'yourprefix_add_to_content' );
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to Pippin's answer, in my case some content were also being shown in other parts of the `single` page, e.g. sidebar. Checking just `is_single()` also triggered the content modification in the other areas. Here's another check so that only the main content will have appended stuff:

```
function yourprefix_add_to_content( $content ) {

    if( is_single() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) {

        if ( $GLOBALS['post']->ID == get_the_ID() ) {

            $content .= 'Your new content here';

        }

    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'yourprefix_add_to_content');
```

Comment: This is the more accurate answer to this question.