# Wordpress after content Hook & external template part

Tags: plugin-development, functions, filters, hooks

I am trying to [use this method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56884/how-to-only-hook-on-single-php-after-content) to include a template part (HTML Code) rather than using some plain text. When I use text, it shows correctly below the content with the the_content filter. However, If I try to get_template_part, the content shows at the top of the Wordpress post rather than below the content.

Is there a better way to include/get template parts hooked to the before/after of single content in Wordpress?

Here is the code I am trying with the filter:

```
function educadme_book_fields_content_hook( $content ) {    
if( is_singular('books') ) {            
$beforecontent = '';
$aftercontent = get_template_part( 'parts/book', 'fields' );
$fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
return $fullcontent;
}
```

Also tried:

```
$content .= get_template_part( 'parts/book', 'fields' );
return $content;
```

Still getting the same issue as all content of the get_template_part are shown above even the title, not just the_content.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since get_template_part and require couldn't be used since they echoed the content above the content and not below (Thanks @benoti), I decided to use a different approach:

```
ob_start(); ?>
<? global $post; ?>

Long HTML Content with some PHP variables inside to load all the custom fields & style I wanted instead of using an external file which I prepared before.

<?php
$book_fields = ob_get_clean();      
$fullcontent = $content . $book_fields;
return $fullcontent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that a mix of `return` and `echo` from a function will change text positioning.

If you take this simple example :

```
function test(){
    $the_test = 'test return';
    echo 'test echo';
    return $the_test;
}

echo test();
```

Whatever the place of the echoed line, this line will be always print before `echo test();` because echo is called before the `return $the_test;`

You need to play with [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) and/or [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action to display your content like you want.

Hope your understand what I mean and the relation with your issue ;-)

Comment: Thanks that's an informative point but I found that I am not using any echo in this particular part. I have updated with code.

Comment: But a template part is echo not return, so everything is render before, like the example.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for explaining that. I am not a developer so that is something for me. Do I then need to change that to include a PHP file or is that also an echo? What do you recommend in my case to output something external? Thanks!

Comment: I just edit my answer. Hope you will find all element to make it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decided to use ob_start to just throw everything in it to a variable and then use it directly. I hope this is reliable haha.

Comment: Oh great, I didn't think about this. I'm tired today ;-)

Comment: Your response still taught me a few things :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a "long HTML Content..." in the middle of your condition, another option is to include the "template part" but not with the `get_template_part` function.

Here is what I did after struggle on the same issue, and it works like a charm :

```
function add_post_switcher($content)
{
    if (is_singular('cp-portfolio')) {
        ob_start();
        require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/post-switcher.php';
        $post_switcher = ob_get_clean();
        $content .= $post_switcher;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_switcher', 1);
```

It's a old post, but hoppefully it'll help someone else :)